# Python - creating a tuple of slices

Tags: python, tuples, slice

I'm trying to create a tuple where each element is a slice, but the slice values depend on its position in the tuple. For example:

```
sl  = (0.1,0.2,0.3)

for i in range(3):
    slic = slice(0,sl(i),0.1) if i==0 else slice(sl(i-1),sl(i),0.1)
```

In this way, I can make the slices I want for every `i`. Now, how can i create a tuple concatenating with all these values? i.e., the first element of the tuple will correspond to `slic` for `i =0`, and so on... Thank you for the comprehension.

Comment: You are indexing using parenthesis `()`, use `[]` for indexing eg. `sl[i-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression:

```
tuple(
    slice(0, sl[i], 0.1) if i==0 else slice(sl[i-1], sl[i], 0.1)
    for i in range(3)
)
```